# Spring-Hibernate with Cassanra DB: Class not found for CassandraCQL2Dialect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, cassandra

I have written a basic sample Spring-Hibernate application for `Cassandra` DB, for that I have taken

1) Person - model class

2) PersonDao - Dao class

3) hbm file - for mapping

4) applicationContext.xml

5) PersonMain - Main class

6) pom.xml

7) Exception Info

Person Model class:-

```
public class Person {
    private int personId;
    private String personName;

    public int getPersonId() {
       return personId;
    }
    public void setPersonId(int personId) {
       this.personId = personId;
    }
    public String getPersonName() {
       return personName;
    }
    public void setPersonName(String personName) {
       this.personName = personName;
    }

}
```

PersonDao:- This class is for DB operations

```
public class PersonDao {
    HibernateTemplate template;
    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template){
        this.template = template;
    }
    public void savePerson(Person p){
        template.save(p);
    }
    public void updatePerson(Person p){
        template.update(p);
    }
    public void deletePerson(Person p){
        template.delete(p);
    }
    public Person getPersonById(int personId){
        return (Person)template.get(Person.class, personId);
    }
    public List<Person> getAllPersons(){
        return template.loadAll(Person.class);
    }
}
```

person.hbm.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sample.spring.bean.Person" table="person">
        <id name="personId" column="person_id"/>
        <property name="personName" column="person_name"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

applicationContect.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
        value="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/user" />
        <!-- <property name="username" value="cassandra"/>
        <property name="password" value="cassandra"/> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>person.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.cassandra.CassandraCQL2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="d" class="com.sample.spring.dao.PersonDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="hibernateTemplate"></property>  
    </bean>
</beans>
```

PersonMain:-

```
public class PersonMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("****** Spring With Hibernate *******");
        ApplicationContext context = new     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        PersonDao dao = context.getBean(PersonDao.class);
        System.out.println("****** Starting Dao Operations *******");

        Person p = new Person();
        p.setPersonId(126);
        p.setPersonName("Sathish");

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setPersonId(124);
        p2.setPersonName("Sathish Kumar");
        // This statement getting executed and I am able to see record in the DB 
        dao.savePerson(p); 
        // After insertion the below print statement is not printing in console and also not executing next statements too
        // i.e after insertion closing the connection
        System.out.println("****** End of Dao Insert *******");
        List<Person> list = dao.getAllPersons();
        list.forEach(person -> {System.out.println(person);});
        System.out.println("****** End of Dao Get All *******");

        Person p1 = dao.getPersonById(123);
        System.out.println(p1);
        System.out.println("****** End of Dao Get *******");
        dao.updatePerson(p1);
        System.out.println("****** End of Dao Update *******");
        dao.deletePerson(p2);
        System.out.println("****** End of Dao Delete *******");
    }

}
```

Pom.xml:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sample.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>Sample-Spring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Sample-Spring</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring-version>3.0.4.RELEASE</spring-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AOP dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache-extras.cassandra-jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.Alpha1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Exception info:-

Now I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.cassandra.CassandraCQL2Dialect` , I added dependency for it also but still gatting this issue

Comment: Just curious, you use Oracle dialect to access Cassandra DB?  By the way, you may want to have some service layer which defines the transaction boundary.

Comment: You apparently don't use transactions (at least I don't see a transaction manager in your configuration). Next you are mixing jars from different versions of Spring never mix versions of a framework. Unify all `org.springframework` dependencies to a single version (currently 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.4, 3.0.5 and 2.5.1 are mixed). (I do however suggest to use Spring Boot instead of plain Spring as well). Finally you apparently use `HibernateTempate` which you shouldn't use anymore instead use a plain `SessionFactory` and use `getCurrentSession` to obtain a session to work with.